# CSS animations - initialise animation at last frame

Tags: css, sass, css-animations

I'm doing some CSS animations inside a modal dialog. Here's the pertinent SCSS:

```
      @keyframes grow {
        from {
          transform: scale(1);
        }
        to {
          transform: scale(1.1);
        }
      }

      @keyframes shrink {
        from {
          transform: scale(1.1);
        }
        to {
          transform: scale(1);
        }
      }

      $duration: 0.5s;
      $animationFillMode: both;

      &:not(.active):hover, &.active {
        img {
          animation: grow $duration $animationFillMode;
        }
      }

      &:not(.active) {
        img {
          animation: shrink $duration $animationFillMode;
        }
      }
```

This works well but the problem is, when I open the modal, the animations kick in immediately. For example, because when the modal is first open I'm not hovering on one of the elements, the element instantly shrinks from big to small. I want the element to start in the small state when the modal is open.

Is is possible? TIA

Comment: Could you put the relevant HTML and associated CSS into your question as well preferably as a working SO snippet.

Comment: don't use animation, you clearly need transtion here since you are defining two opposite animation (this is a task for transition)

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif - can you give an example of this plz

Comment: `.xx{transition:1s}.xx:hover {transform:scale(1.1)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, use reverse tag.

Example: `animation-direction: reverse;`